# Python attempting to create a simple gui, getting "AttributeError: 'MainMenu' object has no attribute 'intro_screen'"

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, attributeerror

complete newbie here to Python as I only started learning the language a few days ago (with no programming experience beforehand).

I'm basically bashing my skull against the desk here, trying to create one menu with a button that will lead you to another menu, which is supposed to replace/hide/destroy the previous menu (either works, so long as the process can be reversed).

What I've come up with so far:

```
import wx


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)

        self.Centre()
        self.main_menu = MainMenu(self)
        self.intro_screen = IntroScreen(self)
        self.intro_screen.Hide()


class MainMenu(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self.main_menu = MainMenu
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        nextscreen = wx.Button(panel, label='Next Screen', size=(150,30))
        nextscreen.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.NextScreen)
        sizer.Add(nextscreen, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.Show()
        self.Centre()

    def NextScreen(self, event):

        self.main_menu.Hide(self)
        self.intro_screen.Show()


class IntroScreen(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        self.intro_screen = IntroScreen
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        gobackscreen = wx.Button(panel, label='Go Back a Screen', size=(150,30))
        gobackscreen.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.GoBackScreen)
        sizer.Add(gobackscreen, 0, wx.CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.Show()
        self.Centre()

    def GoBackScreen(self, event):

        self.intro_screen.Hide()        
        self.main_menu.Show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    #frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

From what I can tell, the NextScreen button does not see the intro_screen class, and is therefore unable to show it. But I am clueless as to how to fix this.

Indeed, I have absolutely no idea if this is on the right way to do it. Any help is greatly appreciated

Using Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intro_screen` is an attribute of `MainFrame` instances; *not* of `MainMenu` instances.

Your `MainMenu.__init__()` method is passed in a `MainFrame` instance as `parent`. I am not certain if `self.parent` is set by the line `wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=parent)`, but if it is not, do add `self.parent = parent` in `MainMenu.__init__(`.

You can then refer to `self.parent` on `MainMenu` instances, and the following should work:

```
self.parent.intro_screen.Show()
```

I am not sure why you are setting the current class as an instance attribute:

```
self.main_menu = MainMenu
```

and

```
self.intro_screen = IntroScreen
```

Instead of `self.main_menu.Hide(self)` you can just call `self.Hide()`, the reference to the class is *not* needed.

Comment: Woo! It worked :D

Thanks a bunch Martijn Pieters.

As to why I am setting the current class as an instance attribute; that is simply because I barely have a sense of what I am doing :)